# Can "go with" be used to suggest a choice?

Tags: word-usage

Can "go with" be used as in the following sentence?

> **A**: What should I do, playing Doom or Hexen II?
>   **B**: I would go with Doom.

The second sentence is making a suggestion. Is it correct/acceptable to use "go with" in that case?

The OALD doesn't show *go with* used as in the example sentence I used.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, this is common usage.

> **go with**  (http://www.thefreedictionary.com/go+with)
>   1. To date (someone) regularly.
>   2. To select or choose: decided to go with the pink wallpaper.